# How to translate word using google translator API?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the converted text using google translator's api.

```
public JsonResult getCultureMeaning(string word, string langcode)
{

    string url = String.Format("https://translate.google.com/#en/" + langcode+ "/" + word + "");
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
    string m = "";
    foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='result_box']").ChildNodes)
    {
        m += node.InnerHtml;
    }
    return Json(m, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In this above method I am passing parameters, say if `word` is `Welcome` and `langcode` is `hi` in this case.

So I would have url https://translate.google.com/#en/hi/welcome and result is `आपका स्वागत है`

But when I do select result container with its children nodes as- `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='result_box']").ChildNodes)` then it does not find this result container within the result. Hence I don't get this api work in my case.

**Edit-**
result container from the url-

```
<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="hi"><span class="hps">आपका स्वागत है</span></span>
```

How should I approach it to get it working. For reference I am using `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Comment: You aren't using the API, you are just trying to exploit their system. Their actual API is explained here: https://developers.google.com/translate/?hl=nl this is a paying service however. Bing translate API is free. http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect page requests, you might notice, that actual translation request done via AJAX, sample query for your translation is: https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=en&tl=hi&hl=en&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qc&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&dt=sw&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&ssel=0&tsel=0&q=welcome

It returns JSON, you might inspect it and get what you looking for(data is pretty big, so i won't post it here)

Answer (score 0):

Agility pack only requests back document elements, It cannot request contents after ajax request is done. Thanks to @Uriil for pointing light on this issue.

However I was able to manage it via traditional way using `WebClient`

**Here is what I did-**

```
 public JsonResult getCultureMeaning(string word, string languagePair)
        {
            string languagePair = "en|" + langua + "";
            string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", word, languagePair);
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
            result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<span title=\"") + "<span title=\"".Length);
            result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(">") + 1);
            result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</span>"));
            result = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(result.Trim());
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

It works for every culture pair. Except converting `en|en`, In this case It would request whole `HTML` document with result.